# Fragment Design

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a problem with fragments in my application. My interface looks like this:

```
Screen 1
+---------------+
|   Fragment 1  |
+---------------+
|   Fragment 2  |
|               |
|               |
+---------------+

Screen 2
+---------------+
|   Fragment 1  |
+---------------+
|   Fragment 3  |
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
```

Each screen is a separate activity and these fragments are defined in my layout .xml files (therefore replacing dynamically probably won't work).

My question is:

Both screen1 and screen2 contain a fragment1, and all the information that goes with it. As it stands, I am currently passing all the data for fragment1 when I start the screen2 activity - I then populate fragment1 in screen2 with the data from fragment1 screen1. If the user hits the back button, I have to populate fragment1 screen1 with whatever was changed in screen2. It's a big headache.

Is there an easier way to do this?

(I'd prefer not to use the single-activity/multiple-fragment approach since I've already been there and decided that multiple-activity/multiple-fragment works better for this application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easier way to do this?

Yes, use a single `Activity`, and have `Fragment 3` `replace` `Fragment 2` when you need to add it, so `Fragment 1` will remain the same with all of its data.

> (I'd prefer not to use the single-activity/multiple-fragment approach since I've already been there and decided that multiple-activity/multiple-fragment works better for this application.)

I'd have to disagree, since you have chosen the harder route by setting your `Fragments` in xml and passing around their data between `Activity`s. I can almost guarantee that is more work than setting `FrameLayout` containers in your layout and then simply adding/replacing `Fragment`s in them.

Simple example - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: This makes sense but why do you suggest FrameLayout? The docs say that FrameLayouts should have only one child...

Comment: Yes, the one child in the `FrameLayout` will be your `Fragment`. If you checkout Google's example, you will see that is what they (and I) prefer to use. I don't think you **have** to use them, but I am unsure what would happen if you used another `ViewGroup` type.

Comment: I've done it your way and it works, Mr. Byle. Thank you. And you, person in the future (if you have this problem), don't be lazy and just do it. It's a lot easier than passing data around and monitoring state.